# LINQ to SQL ToDictionary method

Tags: .net, linq, dictionary

**I have a table with a structure like this:**

Column1 AS INT,

Column2 AS INT,

Column3 AS INT,

Column4 AS DECIMAL

**My LINQ query is this:**

*var query = from t in context.Table select t;*

**I want to convert/transform the query to this Dictionary object:**

*Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, decimal>>>*

using only the ToDictionary method of the LINQ query.  Can it be done?

Comment: @acermate433s, I don't understand how `Column1...Column4` relate to your `Dictionary<Employee, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, decimal>>>`.  Please explain what column you want to match with what part of the dictionary.  And where does `Employee` come in?

Comment: Reading "Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, decimal>>>" is a brainfsk by itself. Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: A dictionary within a dictionary within a dictionary... [Inception](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/)!

Comment: @Kirk: I've edited my question, it should have been an int.

Comment: Basically I want to create a look-up table.  I would want to access the items using this notation Dictionary[][][].Value

Comment: @acermate443s, yes, and isn't that what I gave you below?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will give you what you want:

```
var result = data
    .GroupBy(x => x.Column1)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x
        .GroupBy(y => y.Column2)
        .ToDictionary(y => y.Key, y => y
            .ToDictionary(z => z.Column3, z => z.Column4)));
```

Though I agree with Judah that only ugly code will result from using it.